# Map Callouts from plist in Xcode?

Tags: ios, ios4, mapkit, mkmapview, plist

I was looking at the following discussion of a question to try and understand how to read locations from a plist and drop pins an Map view accordingly:

[MapKit based app crashing when loading from plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600419/mapkit-based-app-crashing-when-loading-from-plist)

I am having problems understanding how to make this work. If I hard code in the annotations then I can make it work fine so I don't understand where I'm going wrong. I think it is probably how I am accessing the data in the .plst. My plist has the structure:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>rowData</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>details</key>
            <string>Some minor info</string>
            <key>latitude</key>
            <strong>53.958756</string>
            <key>Location</key>
            <string>Location One</string>
            <key>lontitude</key>
            <string>-1.07937</string>
        </dict>
       </array>
   </dict>
 </array>
```

I try to access this data using the code from the answer to the question above like this But with not joy:

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{
self = [super init];
if(self!=nil){
    coordinate.latitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    self.title = [dict objectForKey:@"Location"];
    self.subtitle = [dict objectForKey:@"details"];
}
return self;
```

My viewDidLoad also looks a bit different to the other question I referenced above. It looks like this:

```
- (void)gotoLocation
{
    // set location as York, UK
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = 53.960025;
    newRegion.center.longitude = -1.082697;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.0012872;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.0159863;

    [self.map setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}



 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    //Set up map
    self.map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;   // also MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid

    [self gotoLocation];

    // Get the the plist in application bundle
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Places" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Retrieve the plists root element array
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"Grabbed locations.plist ok");

    if (array) {

        NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[array count]];
        for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {
            MapAnnotations* annotation = [[MapAnnotations alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];
            [self.map addAnnotation:annotation];
            [annotation release];
        }
        NSLog(@"The count: %i", [myDict count]);
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Plist does not exist");
    }

}
```

If anyone can explain to me where I am going wrong and how to do what I need to do, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are a couple of problems with the plist (at least with the example in your question):

- `<strong>` (under `latitude` key) should be `<string>`
- `lontitude` should be `longitude`

Next, your plist structure is an array containing one dictionary with one key "rowData" with a value that is an array of dictionaries.  But the code loops through the `array` variable which contains only the outermost array (which only contains the single dictionary with the "rowData" key).  So in `initWithDictionary`, the `objectForKey` calls all return nil  because the location related keys aren't in the outermost dictionary.

You want to either re-structure the plist so that it is just an array of location dictionaries (eliminate the "rowData" dictionary) or update the code to get the array inside the "rowData" key and loop through that:

```
NSArray *rowDataArray = [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"rowData"];
for (NSDictionary* dict in rowDataArray) //instead of "in array"
```

Finally, the `myDict` dictionary is not being used really.  The NSLog of its count will always display zero because the `dictionaryWithCapacity` line just allocates memory but doesn't add any objects.  I don't see a need for the `myDict` variable--I'd remove it.

Comment: Thanks so Much @Anna That solved my problem. As I'm still trying to get my head around working with plists I wonder if you can clarify a point for me? Just looking at the above example, when working with a plist I don't need to go down through it layer by layer to get to the data I need, I can just target a particular aspect of the plist and then go for that? So as in the above instead of targeting the root dictionary and then the next array and then the next dictionary to get to the rowData array, I can just go straight to the row data?

Comment: You might be able to do "direct access" using Key Value Coding (see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/KeyValueCoding.htmlhttp://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/KeyValueCoding.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1)) but the work effort is probably about the same.

Comment: One way or another, you have to know the plist structure and drill down to the object(s) you need.  As I mentioned, in your case, you don't even need the outer array and dictionary with the single rowData key.  You just need the inner array of location dictionaries which will let you use your original code.

Comment: Thank 2Anna. The reason for the structure is because I'm using the same data to populate a table and I need that particular structure. The plist posted above is a snippet of a larger list. I've used key value coding for hard coding objects so I am more familiar with them than plists, though I'm trying to learn more about coding so plists provides more of a learning curve.